# dynamically allocated character device major

Tags: kernel, git

How do I verify which Ubuntu kernel has this patch:
https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/8361751/

Comment: This might helps you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162914/how-can-i-check-if-a-certain-patch-is-already-installed-in-my-system

Comment: thanks for your time. This makes it more difficult. New question :-) how do I browse Ubuntu 16.0.4 kernel 4.10.15 source code? I can then check the source code for the changes.

I went to kernel.org but could not find  4.10.15

Comment: You can install the Linux source as follows: First, check available versions for your system with `apt policy linux-source*`. Then, install the Linux kernel source with `sudo apt install linux-source-[version]` where [version] is whatever is available for your system.

Comment: forgive me. I forgot to add that I don't have Ubuntu. I just want to verify the patch against the kernel version. I want to browse the source code online. The nearest one I found is kernel 4.10.17 (from kernel.org).

Comment: This particular patch is here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/char_dev.c

Comment: @Jos: That's a (possibly patchted) file, not a patch. This is the commit for the above patch: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/49db08c358873af11ba3c25401de88156fa5d365. There's a list of tags that refer to this commit below its message and it shows that this commit was introduced during the merge window of kernel v4.7. It may have been back-ported to earlier kernel versions in Ubuntu though.

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.